# URL Format Query String with /

Tags: java, string, url, slash

Is there anyone her who knows how to use slashes as querystring. What
I want to do is using the url:

http://sample.com/urltest/?id=23423ea342

to appear as

http://sample.com/urltest/23423ea342

and handel it onto the Servlets or Struts Action Class

Comment: that's called URL rewriting, but your question is way too broad for SO. So the best thing to do would be googling those terms and learn a bit more from there.

Comment: Instead you should have correct Servlet of Action class which have method mapped to `http://sample.com/urltest/` and accepts `id` as request parameter

Comment: You could use a regex and replace {'?id='} through '' (an empty string). http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: I dont want a ? Into the query string , it should have only slashes. Is there any tutorial where i can get some idea regarding this ?

Answer (score 0):

add this to `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sample.com/urltest/?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: You should also explain what this does, otherwise the OP learns nothing from this answer.

Comment: In addition to the comment above, you should also mention that the `RewriteRule` above will rewrite any requests since it is `.*` (`^` and `$` are not necessary in this case).

Comment: I have seen many payment gateways or reportieng tools that use this way of url e.g http://www.gateway.com/userauth/txn678257/reportxml/

Answer (score 0):

Well, if i understood what is OP asking for, the simplest way for me to do this is use JAX-RS, aka Java API for RESTful Web Services

Here is the JAX-RS oracle tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html

And here is an example service class for your example URL:

```
@Path("/")
public class testClass {

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}/")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response testMethod(@PathParam(value = "id") String id) {

        return Response.ok().entity("HELLO! You sent me this id: " + id).build();

    }

}
```

Assuming that `/urltest` is the path configured for your base url, this service will be invoked with the following URL:
http://sample.com/urltest/23423ea342

and the "23423ea342" will be your `{id}` parameter for your service